# How can I apply a function to every row of a data frame in R when the function requires multiple inputs?

Tags: r

I need to run a chi squared test on data from each row of a data frame in R. So far I have a function that can create a matrix and run the test on the matrix. This is working fine when I manually enter data into the function.

```
chisquare.table <- function(var1, var2, var3, var4){
  t <- matrix(c(var1, var2, var3, var4), nrow = 2)
  chisq.test(t)

chisquare.table(80, 99920, 85, 99915)
```

However, what I want to do is apply this function to each row of a data frame such that var1 is row *x* column 1, var2 is row *x* column 2, var3 is row *x* column 3, and var4 is row *x* column 4.

I've tried a few different ways with the apply() function but I can't find one that allows me to take the data from the row in the way I want. I'd really appreciate any help or advice on this as I haven't found much online about using apply() with multiple inputs.

Comment: Please show sample of the data frame input and also show what you expect as the output.

Comment: You should consider using `mapply` rather than the suggestion to use `apply`. In this instance there would be a need to rework the function to use with either of these control strategies, but `mapply` is the more forgiving of the two. New R users often get tripped up by the the coercion to matrix objects which in turn coerces factors to integer and coerces the entire result to character if there is a single character object in the list of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are applying the function on each row, use `apply`.  Also, instead of specifying the row elements one by one as arguments (as it can differ for each dataset), use the `...` which can take any number of elements a arguments, and create the `matrix` out of it

```
chisquare.tableMod <- function(...){

     t <- matrix(c(...), nrow = 2) 
      chisq.test(t)

   }

out <- apply(df1, 1, chisquare.tableMod)
```

---

Testing with the output from OP's function

```
chisquare.table <- function(var1, var2, var3, var4){
     t <- matrix(c(var1, var2, var3, var4), nrow = 2)


     chisq.test(t)
  }

outOld <- chisquare.table(80, 99920, 85, 99915)
identical(out[[1]], outOld)
#[1] TRUE
```

As @42- mentioned in the comments, `apply` returns a `matrix` and matrix can hold only single class.  So, select only those columns that are `numeric` while working with `apply` (or only single class)

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(80, 79, 49), v2 = c(99920, 98230, 43240),
      v3  = c(85, 40, 35), v4 = c(99915, 43265, 43238))
```

Comment: I think you should narrow the advisable targets of `apply` to only those that are entirely numeric. Reaching for apply as a replacement of `for`-loop logic is a common source of beginner confusion.

Comment: This is working well. Thank you. I think it would have taken me forever to google this solution.